# how to Place Items on a circle in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing something similar to this
  [image]

I have many ways to acheive this using css and Scss but i couldn't find anything for react native ,if anyone has any idea how to do this.Their help will be much appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use cos and sin function to place the images

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/trusting-bagel

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Highlighter from 'react-native-highlight-words';

const size = 200 ;
const symbolSize = 16;


  const radius = size / 2;
  const center = radius;


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      higightedTexts:''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.setupA(); 
      this.setupB();
      this.setupC();
      this.setupD();
  }

  degToRad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

setupA(){
  const angleRad = this.degToRad(0);
      const x = radius * Math.cos(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      const y = radius * Math.sin(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      this.setState({
        x:  x,
        y: y
      })
}

setupB(){
  const angleRad = this.degToRad(90);
      const x = radius * Math.cos(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      const y = radius * Math.sin(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      this.setState({
        x2:  x,
        y2: y
      })
}

setupC(){
  const angleRad = this.degToRad(180);
      const x = radius * Math.cos(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      const y = radius * Math.sin(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      this.setState({
        x3:  x,
        y3: y
      })
}

setupD(){
  const angleRad = this.degToRad(270);
      const x = radius * Math.cos(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      const y = radius * Math.sin(angleRad) + center - symbolSize / 2;
      this.setState({
        x4:  x,
        y4: y
      })
}






  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center' }}>
        <View
      style={[{backgroundColor:'red',
        width: size,
        height: size,
        borderRadius: size / 2,
      }]}
    >
       <Image
        style={{width: 40,
            height: 40,
            borderRadius:20,
            left: this.state.x-20,
            top: this.state.y ,
            position:'absolute'}}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png',
        }}
      />

       <Image
        style={{width: 40,
            height: 40,
            borderRadius: 20,
            left: this.state.x2,
            top: this.state.y2-20 ,
            position:'absolute'}}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png',
        }}
      />



       <Image
        style={{width: 40,
            height: 40,
            borderRadius: 20,
            left: this.state.x3,
            top: this.state.y3 ,
            position:'absolute'}}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png',
        }}
      />

      <Image
        style={{width: 40,
            height: 40,
            borderRadius: 20,
            left: this.state.x4-10,
            top: this.state.y4,
            position:'absolute'}}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png',
        }}
      />

    </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: i have tried your code in my application but i am getting this error
index.bundle?platfor…&minify=false:25150 Invariant Violation: [773,"RCTImageView",41,{"width":40,"height":40,"overflow":"hidden","borderRadius":20,"top":"<<NaN>>","position":"absolute","shouldNotifyLoadEvents":false,"src":[{"uri":"https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png"}],"defaultSrc":null,"loadingIndicatorSrc":null}] is not usable as a native method argument

Comment: Your image view component is giving error try placing a simple view.

Comment: Pramod how can i do that ?

Comment: try this :----------> https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/grounded-orange

Comment: @ Pramod  it is working now the issue was that you haven't initialized your values in the state e.g x,y,x2,y2 etc and since we are using componentDidMount life cycle hook which is called after the page is rendered and when the page renders its get a NoN top value since it isn't in the state so it showed error.

Comment: @ Pramod Thank you once again

Comment: @Eddy if this solves your issue please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

React native doesn't have any special library do this you can do this by using CSS:

You can do something like this:

```
import { Dimensions, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component{
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>

     <View
        style = {{
          borderRadius: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width + Dimensions.get('window').height) / 2,
          width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8,
          height: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8,
          borderWidth:5,
          borderColor:"red",
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }}
        underlayColor = '#ccc'
      >
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",bottom:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.7}} />
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",bottom:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,right: 20}} />
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",bottom:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,left: 20}} />
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",top:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.7}} />
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",top:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,right: 20}} />
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",top:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.6,left: 20}} />
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",bottom:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.3,left:-20}} />
               <Image source={require('./assets/main.jpg')} style={{height:50,width:50,position:"absolute",bottom:Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.3,right:-20}} />
      </View>
        </View>

    )
}
}
export default App;
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: user code works but is there way where we can make it work dynamic instead of static

Comment: thak you for your answer